# Socket.io connected but not communicating

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a very simple configuration in a node server with socket.io installed (a little bit more complex but essentially like this one):

```
var main = require('express')();
    server = require('http').createServer(main);
    io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  console.log("middleware!");
  next();
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connected...');

  socket.on('pong', function (data) {
    console.log(data.message);
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Saying hello");
    socket.emit('ping', { message: 'Hello from server ' + Date.now() });

  }, 1000);

});

server.listen(2080, function onCreateServerMain() {
  console.log('Server main is listening on port 2080';
  console.log('************************************************************');
});
```

In the client:

```
var socketIoScript,
    loadSocketTimeout,
    trialsToLoadSocketIo = 0,
    APP_CFG = {baseUrl : "http://192.168.1.13:2080"};

function loadSocketIo(socketIoIp) {
  socketIoScript = document.createElement('script');
  socketIoScript.setAttribute('src', socketIoIp);
  socketIoScript.setAttribute('onload', 'onSocketLoaded();');
  document.head.appendChild(socketIoScript);
}

window.onSocketLoaded = function onSocketLoaded() {
  if (typeof(io.connect) === 'function') {
    var mSocket,
        mIoSocket;

    $timeout.cancel(loadSocketTimeout);
    mIoSocket = new io.Manager(APP_CFG.baseUrl);

    mIoSocket.connect(function(socket) {
      console.log('Connected!!');
    });
    mIoSocket.on('error', function onSocketError(e) {
      console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
    });

    mIoSocket.on('ping', function onPingReceived(e) {
      console.log('Server emitted ping: ' + e.data);
      mSocket.emit('pong', 'hi server!');
    });
  }
}

~(function onLoadSocketTimeout() {
  var nextTimeout;

  if (trialsToLoadSocketIo < 10) {
    nextTimeout = 5000;
  } else if (trialsToLoadSocketIo > 60) {
    nextTimeout = 60000;
  } else {
    nextTimeout = 1000 * trialsToLoadSocketIo;
  }

  if (socketIoScript) {
    document.head.removeChild(socketIoScript);
  }

  loadSocketIo(APP_CFG.baseUrl + '/socket.io/socket.io.js#' + trialsToLoadSocketIo);
  loadSocketTimeout = $timeout(onLoadSocketTimeout, nextTimeout);
  trialsToLoadSocketIo += 1;
})();
```

(I'm doing like this because it's mobile app so it may have not connection). I'm testing it with Brackets and Chrome. Server and client are in the same machine. In the app the script is loaded fine and it connects to the server as I can it see in node log *(edit: and this is all what I get in the node console)*:

```
Server main is listening on port 2080
************************************************************
middleware!
connected...
Saying hello
```

*Edit: in Chrome console I don't get any message, and any breakpoint stops at `on` listeners.* If I stop node, the console for the *Chrome* immediately starts logging that it has been disconnected:

```
GET http://192.168.1.13:2080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1413066902601-6 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 
GET http://192.168.1.13:2080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1413066906606-7 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

But I can't see any incoming message. In the app I don't receive any incoming message. Is there any reason why I could not communicate in this environment even if socket is successfully connected?

**EDIT**

No app is receiving events sent from the other side. Logs from node show this, logs from Chrome are empty.

**EDIT**

In Chrome app I don't receive `console.log("Connected!");`. But neither I receive `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` errors: I don't receive anything.

**EDIT**

I managed to get `console.log("Connected!");` in the app by changing Manager options:

```
  mIoSocket = new io.Manager(APP_CFG.baseUrl, { autoConnect: false });
```

As it was auto connecting and the events were attached after connection was made, "Connected" was never reached. But I'm still not receiving any event in any app.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the app I don't receive any incoming message"?  Are you asking about client or server?  And, when are you expecting a message when you don't get one.  Sorry, but it is just not clear about exactly what circumstance you're asking about.  Are you aware that the `socket.io` client has auto-reconnect logic and will report the disconnnect when the reconnect logic has expired?

Comment: If you post a question, some viewers find the question is not clear to them and they ask clarifying questions, but you aren't around to answer those questions, then you will miss most of the opportunities for people to answer your question.  The large majority of people who see your question will happen in the first hour after you post.  If you aren't around then to clarify things, you will miss most people who could help you.  This place does not work like a forum where you post and come back tomorrow.  Your question may be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @jfriend00 +1 on all the stuff you've said. OP : does the `console.log('Connected!!')` outputs anything to your console?

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" since the question is unclear and the OP is not responding to calls to clarify.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are right about timings, I had to go. No application is getting events from each other. There are no logs from `on` listeners in the logs and so I din't thought it could be unclear. Anyway I'm going to edit it to be more precise as the question is large and some things may be over read in a fast reading.

Comment: @jfriend00 Would you mind checking my answer and see if you spot more things that go wrong? there's so many I might have overlooked something and I'd appreciate your expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so a few things :

First, `var mSocket` doesn't seem to be initialized, so it may be difficult for it to emit() anything (am I missing something?)

Second, when you do :

```
socket.on('pong', function (data) {
    console.log(data.message);
});
```

the server expects to receive an object containing a `message` property, eg : `data = {message:'hi server'}` In your case, you send a string, so `data` is `'Hi server !'` and your log will say  'undefined'. You should change this bit to :

```
socket.on('pong', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

and you have a similar problem the other way around, you send an object : `{ message: 'Hello from server ' + Date.now() }`, and are trying to log a `data` property which does not exist. Change this bit to :

```
  console.log('Server emitted ping: ' + e.message);
```

And third , you have to listen for events on the socket, not the 'manager'

**Client :**

```
mIoSocket.connect(function(socket) {
    console.log('Connected!!');
    socket.emit('pong');

    socket.on('error', function onSocketError(e) {
        console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
    });

    socket.on('ping', function onPingReceived(e) {
        console.log('Server emitted ping: ' + e.data);
        socket.emit('pong', 'hi server!');
    });
});
```

**Server :**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connected...');

  socket.on('pong', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Saying hello");
    socket.emit('ping', { message: 'Hello from server ' + Date.now() });

  }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact resolved 1 min ago by setting `mIoSocket = new io(APP_CFG.baseUrl);` which it was where the problem was, as you pointed, listening events in manager. (other errors some of them were because of simplification for the question :~)

Comment: and others were plain old typos ;) I know the feeling, glad I could help somehow

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue were event callbacks on the server were not firing when emitting. My event names were `ping` and `pong`. As soon as I renamed these events everything worked.

I suspect the event names `ping` and `pong` are reserved by socket.io and so cannot be used.